# How to skip a bad host when generating an asyncore.dispatcher object?

Tags: python, asyncore

```
import asyncore

class HTTPClient(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, path):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket()
        self.connect( (host, 80) )
        self.buffer = bytes('GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n' %
                            (path, host), 'ascii')

    def handle_connect(self):
        pass

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()

    def handle_read(self):
        print(self.recv(8192))

    def writable(self):
        return (len(self.buffer) > 0)

    def handle_write(self):
        sent = self.send(self.buffer)
        self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]


client = HTTPClient('www.bocaonews.com.br', '/')
asyncore.loop()
```

And an error was raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "***.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.connect( (host, 80) )
  File "***\lib\asyncore.py", line 339, in connect
    err = self.socket.connect_ex(address)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

The HTTP client is the example of the official documentation. The error was raised because the host www.bocaonews.com.br is not accessible.

So my question is how to modify the code to let a client automatically close the connection when the host is bad? I can examine the host before generating the dispatcher. But it is less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

asyncore doesn't offer much in the way of simplified error handling.  Mostly, it leaves you responsible for this.  So the solution is to add error handling to your application code:

```
try:
    client = HTTPClient('www.bocaonews.com.br', '/')
except socket.error as e:
    print 'Could not contact www.bocaonews.com.br:', e
else:
    asyncore.loop()
```

To make your life a little easier, you may not want to call `connect` inside `HTTPClient.__init__`.

Also, for comparison, here's a Twisted-based HTTP/1.1 client:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import Agent

a = Agent(reactor)
getting = a.request(b"GET", b"http://www.bocaonews.com.br/")
def got(response):
    ...
def failed(reason):
    print 'Request failed:', reason.getErrorMessage()
getting.addCallbacks(got, failed)
reactor.run()
```